# Tool to create animated SVGs?

Tags: animation, svg

Are there any graphical tools to create and edit animated SVG images? Inkscape is great, but it does everything *except* animation. I created an image in Inkscape, then manually edited the XML to add animation properties; and this gave me what I wanted, but for slightly more complicated designs it can be very tedious.

Comment: Related question: https://superuser.com/questions/171677/are-there-programs-to-create-and-edit-svg-animations

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You might want to have a look at [Synfig](http://synfig.org).
When I needed to make something in this line, used SVG frames, and editing the xml, as you did.

Not free, but cheap, have a look at [Koolmoves](http://www.koolmoves.com) .It has svg export. I like the tool.
(Anyway, consider other exports, like SWF or HTML 5, more future-proof, and better supported in available editors. Disregard this if you totally need svg export.)

Comment: Something to consider about things today with 20/20 hindsight. SWF which is supposedly more futureproofer than SVG anim, SWF is in fact dead. While svg animations still exist just as they did then, still not a big success.

Comment: I think it's also worth pointing out that (on the web) a lot of animations that were previously done with tools like Flash are now often done with JavaScript. If I recall correctly, SVG animations are usually achieved by running js code.

Answer (score 2):

There is a commercial non-free tool made for creating SVG animation similar to Macromedia Dreamviewer and Microsoft expression blend:

https://aphalina.com/

Disclaimer: A friend of mine made this product. I don't work for him.

Answer (score 0):

Try http://archer.graphics - not exactly animation but you can go quite far with it when you know how to write javascript code

Comment: Please explain better how to solve the given question.  As it stands now this is more a link-only answer ... Welcome to GD.SE!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using Blender or Synfig Studio.
Synfig Studio would be great if you want only 2D.

Blender can import and use SVG, it is used for 3D but you can setup camera's to use it in 2D.

Answer (score 0):

If you just simply want to animate an SVG and export a single animated SVG file with clean code, I would recommend [SVGator](https://www.svgator.com).
I've tried other tools, but SVGator is the best one so far. It doesn't require any coding skills, but in case you need some help getting started you can check out their [tutorials](https://www.svgator.com/tutorials).